# Difference between Async.function and Async.procedure in cadence

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow, uber-cadence

Team,

I don't know the difference between `Async.function and Async.procedure`

Let me know when to use where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Async.function`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.uber.cadence/cadence-client/3.1.0/com/uber/cadence/workflow/Async.html#function-com.uber.cadence.workflow.Functions.Func-) can return a value but [`Async.procedure`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.uber.cadence/cadence-client/latest/com/uber/cadence/workflow/Async.html) doesn't.

Also, Functions.Func1 allow to pass a parameter, Functions.Func2 allow to pass two parameters, etc

Comment: we can pass a maximum of 6 params in both Async.Function and Async.procedure right ? Why did it fix as 6?

Comment: It's just a limitation in Java functional programming. To have more, we have to define those interfaces which is a bit tedious and we have to stop at a certain number. And also it's not a good practice to have too many parameters, we just pick 6. You should pass in an wrapper of more parameters as a workaround.